Why am I not receiving e-mails when someone uses auto-fill in Outlook?
I just noticed that whenever someone uses auto fill for my name or e-mail address in Outlook, I don't get any e-mails. I saw that people had such issues earlier, but I was able only to find similar issues when someone is sending e-mail, but not when receiving.
It is happening only in Outlook and when someone uses autofill. Aside from Outlook, we tested it via Thunderbird, Gmail and Exchange and all the e-mails were normally sent (both when using auto fill and when not using it). Do you have any idea how can I resolve this?
I have a lot of customers and it would be unprofessional, but also very difficult to ask from them to check out the auto fill box in Outlook..
Here is a error message:
Generierender Server: ex1.2f-leuchten.com
IMCEAEX-_o=2F-Leuchten_ou=Exchange+20Administrative+20Group+20+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_cn=Recipients_cn=user07c2247c@2f-leuchten.com
Remote Server returned '550 5.1.11 RESOLVER.ADR.ExRecipNotFound; Recipient not found by Exchange Legacy encapsulated email address lookup'
Ursprüngliche Nachrichtenköpfe:
Received: from ex1.2f-leuchten.com (30.0.99.38) by ex1.2f-leuchten.com
 (30.0.99.38) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256) id 15.1.2308.14; Tue, 9 Apr
 2024 16:24:14 +0200
Received: from ex1.2f-leuchten.com ([30.0.99.38]) by ex1.2f-leuchten.com
 ([30.0.99.38]) with mapi id 15.01.2308.014; Tue, 9 Apr 2024 16:24:14 +0200
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: Daniel Falkner <Daniel.Falkner@2f-leuchten.com>
To: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Clemens_Brandst=E4tter?=
    <Clemens.Brandstaetter@2f-leuchten.com>
Subject: test1
Thread-Topic: test1
Thread-Index: AdqKiZbFJ6MNLDIQQVe9VLOrCoclyQ==
Date: Tue, 9 Apr 2024 16:24:14 +0200
Message-ID: <020b204acdce41dbb59ebe05af83cb55@2f-leuchten.com>
Accept-Language: de-AT, de-DE, en-US
Content-Language: de-DE
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <020b204acdce41dbb59ebe05af83cb55@2f-leuchten.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Originating-IP: [30.0.99.170]
Return-Path: Daniel.Falkner@2f-leuchten.com

Did anyone encounter with similar problem? Does anyone has any recommendation what to do?

has your email address changed while you were at this organization? Outlook does cache email addresses, so if it changes, the people who have previoulsy emailed you may need to delete the cached entry for your address so its selected from the address book again. it may also be helpful to verify the address in your account directory (usually active directory) and in the outlook address book.

Is your email address user07c2247c@2f-leuchten.com? If so, then the email administrator needs to associate that address with your account on the Outlook server.

The header shows IMCEAEX, which means that a user within your organisation tries to email with a cached account from the old server, while the email server changed to a new server. You can either remove the old auto-complete name in outlook, alter properties on the email server as a temporary fix, or wait a month until the cache is automatically refreshed.

How long has this been happening? Can't you receive or send emails using OWA?

I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Is there any update on this case?

Hi, thank you for your pieces of advice. I managed to solve the problem. I added address user07c2247c@2f-leuchten.com to the exchange server under alias e-mail for the personal account that had issues with e-mail and right now it seems to be working normal.

Looks like exchange config maintenance was done which broke you somehow. IE an old mapping is gone or your address book entry is invalidly encoded etc. Your IT dept should readily know if you tell them when the change occured.
